# how to return longest words from an array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
given 2 arrays wrds[] , chars[] as an input to a function such that 
wrds[] = [ "abc" , "baa" , "caan" , "an" , "banc" ] 
chars[] = [ "a" , "a" , "n" , "c" , "b"]
```

Function should return the longest word from words[] which can be constructed from the     chars in chars[] array. 
  for above example - "caan" , "banc" should be returned

Note: Once a character in chars[] array is used, it cant be used again. 
 `eg: words[] = [ "aat" ]`
 `characters[] = [ "a" , "t" ]`
  then word "aat" can't be constructed, since we've only 1 "a" in chars[].

There are kinds of anwers online but they are not written in Objective C.Can anyone help   me solve this question in OC?

Comment: show you own try to solve this homework

Comment: this is not the homework.This is an question from apple interview I saw from a website.Its interesting.I can easily find out the longest words in wrds[].But I dont know how to make sure the words is constructed for chars[].

Comment: "There are kinds of anwers online but they are not written in Objective C." - what problem did you encountered when you tried to implement the algorithm(s) these used in Objective-C? Note that your arrays as given are C-arrays of C-strings, so a C solution is directly applicable as an "Objective-C" one.

Answer (score 2):

First, walk through the word array, one word at a time, throwing out all the words that *can't* be formed from the second array. To do that, for each word, walk through the characters of the word, throwing out that character from the second array. If we come to a character that's not in the second array, that word can't be formed from those characters.

Now we have an array consisting solely of the words that *can* be formed from those characters. Now sort that array by word length, longest first. Now start walking the array, looking at the length of each word. When that length value changes, stop; you have found all the longest words.

Comment: Shouldn't you also check words for duplicate characters to remove those as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Program do to do the same in C++  
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;  
using std::vector;
vector<char*> match(char** words, int size, char* chars, map<char,int> &second)  
{  
vector<char*> res;  
std::map<char,int> mapi = second;
int currsize = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){  
    char* wo;  
    wo = words[i];  
    int s= 0;  
    for( s=0; wo[s] != '\0'; s++){  
    }  
    if(s < currsize) {  
        //No need to iterate if already found a bigger word
        //continue to see if the next word if bigger of the same size as currsize
        continue;  
     }  
     // iterate through the map to see if all the letters present in the first array  
     bool found = true;
    for(int j = 0; j <s ; j++){  
        map<char, int>::iterator it = mapi.find(wo[j]);  
        if(it == mapi.end()) { 
             found= false;
              break;  
        }   
    } 
    if(!found) {
     continue;
    }
     if(s > currsize) {  
        //remove the past res as found a bigger one  
        res.clear();  
    }  
    //Store this word in the vector as it is one of the biggest word so far
    res.push_back(wo);  
    currsize = s;  
}  
return res;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    map<char, int> leters;   
    char* words[5] = {"adc", "baa", "caan", "daanns", "banc"};  
    char ch1[]= {'a', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'b'};  
    int chsize = sizeof(ch1);  
    // put the ch1 chars in a map  
    for(int i = 0; i < chsize; i++) {  
        map<char,int>::iterator it =leters.find(ch1[i]);  
        if(it != leters.end()) {  
            it->second = it->second+1;  
        } else {  
            leters.insert(make_pair(ch1[i], 1));  
        }  
    }  
    char* chars = ch1;   
    vector<char*>v = match(words, 5, ch1, leters);  
    for(vector<char*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {  
        // it will print the result  
        cout <<  *it  << endl;   
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```